# How to show a special string for a column when exporting using laravel-excel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using laravel excel to export data from 'User' table. A query needs to be run and all the records that match the query will return.

My code is like

```
class UsersExport implements FromQuery
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(string $code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Tantousya::query()->where('code','>=',$this->code); 
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly and giving me correct data.

However, in the User table there is a "password" column. The clients want me to show strings like "*****" instead of showing the encrypted password. If no password is set then show ""(a blank string).

To illustrate it better, my current output is like,
[image]

My desired output is like, 
[image]

How can I change my query function in such a way that I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

```
public function query()
{
    return Tantousya::query()->select(['*', \DB::raw("'***' as password")])->where('code','>=',$this->code); 
}
```

The second way is to implement [**FromCollection**](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html) then use the [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections#introduction) method to change values.

Something like this:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UserExport implements FromCollection {

    public function collection()
    {
        return User::select(['*'])
            ->get()
            ->map(function($item) {
                $collection = $item;
                $collection['password'] = '***';
                return $collection;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the second way properly. Can you please elaborate it?